# Connected planar compact set with finite length is path connected

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-measure-theory

Here length means 1-Hausdorff measure. This seems to be known, what is the reference? Or very short proof?

Comment: What about the standard example of a connected, non-path connected set? Each simplex will have image in one of the two path components, so cohomology will be the direct sum of the two cohomologies which then both are zero as each path component is contractible.

Comment: @Antonius Sorry, I do not understand what example you are talking about. For me a standard example is topologist's sine, and what are simplices?

Comment: You need simplices to compute cohomology, that is, singular cohomology. Since your condition is that the first cohomology be finite.

Comment: What is $H^1$-length?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I had to specify that $\mathcal{H}^1$ is a Hausdorff measure

Comment: Theorem 4 of the paper by M H A Newman titled Path Length and Linear measure Proc London Math Soc (3) 2 year 1952 pages 455-468 maybe relevant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See Exercise 3.5 in "The geometry of fractal sets" by K. J. Falconer.

It says that any such set is an image of rectifiable curve.

For a short proof, check "Rectifiable curve" in [my collection](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0290).

P.S. The earliest reference I found: Theorem 2 in *Continua of finite linear measure. I.* by Eilenberg and Harrold (1943).